# How to get one of everything in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have something like this:

```
id   title   url            revision
-------------------------------------
1    blah    someurl        1
2    blah    someurl        2
3    other   someotherurl   1
4    other   someotherurl   2
```

So I have two revisions of two different entries. Is there a way, through SQL, to SELECT just the latest revision of the latest documents?

IE: The query would return rows 2 and 4 because they're the latest revisions, and it would exclude selecting older revisions.

Comment: are the `blah`s `other`s and so on always the same for every revision?

Comment: There is ambiguity in your question. You probably want the latest revision of EACH document, but as stated, your question could also mean just those documents whose revision number is equal to the MAX revision number. Please clear this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM YOUR_TABLE x
  JOIN (SELECT t.title, 
               MAX(t.revision) AS max_rev
          FROM YOUR_TABLE t
      GROUP BY t.title) y ON y.title = x.title
                         AND y.max_rev = x.revision
```

Because MySQL doesn't support analytic functions (ROW_NUMBER), this approach is flawed -- if you have the same title, and more than one of those has the same lowest `revision`, all of those with that lowest `revision` for that title will be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT title , max(revision)

FROM your_table

GROUP BY title`

I am just unsure if it should be titles or urls in the query

Answer (score 0):

When `title` and `url` are the same for every revision then use

```
SELECT y.* FROM (
    SELECT MAX(revision) AS revision,title,url FROM <TABLE> GROUP BY title,url
) x INNER JOIN <TABLE> y ON x.title=y.title AND x.url=y.url AND x.revision=y.revision
```

Comment: I don't believe we can safely assume at this point in time that the max(ID) would match Max(revision) per title/url. This would assume A) identity column and B) no ability to update revision #'s